# Get a count of (active) timers in Node.js event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, v8, libuv

Is there a way to make a call in Node.js to determine the number of timers in the event loop queue? I have a library with a number of timeouts and instead of keeping track of them myself using some sort of internal bookkeeping system, it would be nice if I could just ask V8 or Libuv or whatever, how many timers there are.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you believe overwriting setTimeout method with a wrapper that manages a counter would fit your needs?

Comment: @DavidRissatoCruz that might work, yeah, although, you'd also have to monkeypatch clearTimeout as well

Answer (score 3):

> it would be nice if I could just ask V8 or Libuv or whatever

You cannot directly *ask libuv*, but it certainly offers a way to know how many active timers are there.
To do that, you can invoke [`uv_walk`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/loop.html#c.uv_walk_cb) with a valid loop to get all the active handles. Then you can check each handle with the given callback and count those for which the data member `type` (that has type [`uv_handle_type`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html#c.uv_handle_type)) is equal to `UV_TIMER`.
The result is the number of active timers.

See the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html) for further details about the handle data structure.

---

As a trivial example, consider the following structure:

```
struct Counter {
    static int count;

    static void callback(uv_handle_t* handle, void*) {
        if(handle.type == uv_handle_type::UV_TIMER) count++;
    }
};
```

You can use it as it follows:

```
Counter::count = 0;
uv_walk(my_loop_ptr, &Counter::callback);
// Counter::count indicates how many active timers are running on the loop
```

Of course, this is not a production-ready code. Anyway, I hope it gives an idea of the proposed solution.

---

See [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) for the libuv documentation.